# En la parte de abajo del footer se crea un espacio en blanco

Tags: html, css, css3

**[image: texto en negrita]**

Se crea el espacio en blanco: no sé aún por qué lo hace. ¿Alguien sabe cuál podría ser la solución?

Comment: ¿A que espacio en blanco te refieres?

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mas a que te refieres con espacio blanco? en que parte de la web?

Comment: En la parte de abajo del footer se crea un espacio en blanco

Comment: Bueno, no es que se cree ese espacio en blanco, es que la resolucion es la que es... fíjate que arriba pone que es 800*876.  Si lo que quieres decir es que quieres bajar el footer hasta abajo es otra cosa, pero entonces el espacio en blanco estara en medio con esa resolución, claro.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no todos pueden ver las imágenes: adjunta un [repro]. Lee [ask].

Comment: Esto te sucede porque no tienes suficiente contenido. la solucion es tan simple como ponerle al body un min-height de 100vh.

Answer (score 2):

Solo con css ponle al footer position: fixed; bottom:0; width: 100%

Comment: Cuando tenga mas contenido el footer se le quedara visible estilo header y no al final de la pagina.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes ocupar la propiedad `display: grid` aplicado al body, y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh
}

body {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body header,
body footer{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
          Header
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            Todo tu contenido
        </div>
        <footer>
          Footer
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solucioné de la siguiente manera, en mi caso es un form en el tuyo un section por lo que veo, entonces solo agrégale la propiedad de `style: min-height` y puedes empezar desde `100vh` e ir bajando hasta que este en el punto que quieres.

A footer no le harías nada

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server" style="min-height: 82vh">
      </form>
      <footer>
      <footer/>
</body>
</html>
```